# Django URL complicated patterns and paths

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to generated nested url paths. So far I could only generate 1 level urls. When I try second level urls it doesn't get called anymore, it still only shows the first level url although the address bar on the browser does direct to the second level url. Is this possible or do I need to create a new app?

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, TemplateView
from dashboard.models import IPARate,PCPRate
from dashboard import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^medicare/', ListView.as_view(queryset=IPARate.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='dashboard/medicare.html')),
    url(r'^medicare/medicarepcp/$', ListView.as_view(queryset=PCPRate.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='dashboard/medicarepcp.html')),
    url(r'^medicare/', views.medicaid, name='medicare'),
    url(r'^medicare/medicarepcp/$', views.medicarepcp, name='medicarepcp'),

]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add a dollar (end of line character) to the `r'^medicare/` regex, so that it matches `/medicare/` but not other URLs like `medicare/medicarepcp/`.

```
url(r'^medicare/$', ListView.as_view(queryset=IPARate.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='dashboard/medicare.html')),
url(r'^medicare/medicarepcp/$', ListView.as_view(queryset=PCPRate.objects.all().order_by("id"), template_name='dashboard/medicarepcp.html')),
```

The third and the fourth regexes are the same as the first and the second respectively. Django will always match the first two URL patterns, so you need to change the third and fourth URL patterns to something else.

Answer (score 1):

The order of URLs is important, as Django will react to the first URL pattern that matches the request. A good habit is to put all of your "sub" URLs first, then the top level of that section last, so it works as a fall-back if no others match (i.e. put your '^medicare/$' last).